# Style changes between controls and graphics

Tags: graphics, manipulate, fonts

In the following `Manipulate`, the style (font?) of the *a* changes between when it is a control label and when it is a label in the graphics.

Is there a way to make the 'control a' look like the 'graphics a'?

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
  Style[Text["a", {0, 0}], Italic, 14]},
  Axes -> False, PlotRange -> 3, ImageSize -> {100, 100}, 
  GridLines -> None],

 {{a, 0, Style[Text["a"], Italic, 14]}, 0, 100, 1}]
```

I can't find anything in the stylesheet, that can help me. I have set the font of `Output` to *'Georgia'*, but I assume that I need to select the font somewhere else too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to do it; perhaps simpler than Jens method.

```
Manipulate[Graphics[
   {Style[Text["a", {0, 0}], Italic, 14]},
   Axes -> False, PlotRange -> 3, ImageSize -> {100, 100}, GridLines -> None],
 {{a, 0, Style["a", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"]}, 0, 100, 1}]
```

[image: manipulate]

Comment: Why do you need `Row` here?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Thanks for pointing it out. Just a bad habit I've gotten into, writing Row[{...}] automatically when I start a labeling expression because it makes editing the label to add further elements easy. I have edited the answer to remove the offending `Row.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that there is a simpler form than shown in the other two answers, but I may be forgetting something.

Using `Style[..., "Graphics"]` seems more accurate to me than simply using a fixed typeface, and cleaner than the `FormBox`/`TraditionalForm` construct.

(Font made big for greater visibility.)

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics[{Style[Text["a", {0, 0}], Italic, 30]}, Axes -> False,
    PlotRange -> 3, ImageSize -> {100, 100}, GridLines -> None],
  {{a, 0, Style["a", "Graphics", Italic, 30]}, 0, 100, 1}
]
```

[image]

- For even greater brevity, if one accepts a fixed typeface, you can use style `"TI"` (Times italic), e.g. `Style["a", "TI", 30]`
- You can use `LabelStyle` (thanks, [Mike](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/77/mike-honeychurch)) to affect all labels at once

Example:

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics[{Style[Text["a", {0, 0}], Italic, 30]}, Axes -> False,
    PlotRange -> 3, ImageSize -> {100, 100}, GridLines -> None],
  {a, 0, 100, 1},
  LabelStyle -> {"TI", 30}
]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 - cool to use named styles, makes it clearer.

Comment: I'd do it that way (named style) as well. Maybe also add a variation in which you make use of `LabelStyle` rather than use `Style` within the `Manipulate` label. Makes it cleaner IMO

Comment: @Mike Great idea!

Answer (score 3):

The default form for `Text` in `Graphics` is `TraditionalForm`, but it's not the same in the slider label of `Manipulate`. So you have to hard-code the desired form and also the fonts, if desired. For example, with `Times` font:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Style[Text["a", {0, 0}], FontFamily -> "Times", Italic, 
    14]}, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> 3, ImageSize -> {100, 100}, 
  GridLines -> None], {{a, 0, 
   DisplayForm@
    FormBox[StyleBox["a", FontFamily -> "Times"], TraditionalForm]}, 
  0, 100, 1}]
```

[image: fonts]