# What are all the named Mathematica styles?

Tags: output-formatting, undocumented

This question came to mind because of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29518/3066) to a recent question.

Under Style, the *Mathematica* Documentation Center says the following about named styles.

> A few common named styles include: "Button", "Graphics", ..., "Title"

Altogether it lists 13 named styles, but the phrase "a few of" implies there are more. Other cell styles such as "SubTitle" and "SubSubSection" come to mind. But strings other than those naming cell styles evidently qualify as named styles. In the referenced answer, Mr.Wizard uses "TI" as a named style for the "Times Italic" font.

```
Style["The quick brown fox ...", "TI"]
```

[image: TI.png]

By trial and error, I have found these addition named styles:

```
"TR"   (Times Roman -- plain Times)
"TB"   (Times Bold)
"TBI"  (Times Bold Italic)
"SR"   (Sans serif Roman -- plain sans serif)
"SB"   (Sans serif Bold)
"SO"   (Sans serif Oblique)
"SBO"  (Sans serif Bold Oblique)
```

I wonder what other named styles exist, other than cell styles, that *Mathematica* will accept in a `Style` expression. I further wonder what sort of spelunking in *Mathematica* would turn them up.

Comment: Related: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/Jun/msg00353.html

Comment: As per @MichaelE2 link the available built-in style names are specified in the default and the core stylesheets.

Comment: @MichaelE2. That link seems to answe my first question. Thanks.

Comment: Note that the function used no longer works (V8 and later, at least).

Comment: @m_goldberg, more generally, what are all the named options for all built in symbols?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
nb2 = NotebookOpen @ FileNameJoin[
  {$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets", "Core.nb"}];
```

Note that some of the named styles in the core stylesheet styles are empty, i.e. the style name is defined but no styles set:

```
Cell[StyleData["style"]]
```

For example (with V8):

```
Union[Cases[NotebookGet[nb2],StyleData[x_, ___] :> x, \[Infinity]]] // Length   
(* 526 *)

Union[Cases[NotebookGet[nb2],Cell[StyleData[x_, ___], __] :> x, \[Infinity]]] // Length    
(* 477 *)
```

Those style names with some style settings defined are (note the repeated `All` at the start of the output list due to the style environment names. You can modify if you wanted to use this programmatically in some way):

```
styles=Union[Cases[NotebookGet[nb2], Cell[StyleData[x_,___], __] :> x, \[Infinity]]]

(* {"Abs", "ActionMenu", "ActionMenuLabel", "AddOnsLink", \
"AddOnsLinkText", "AiryAi", "AiryAiPrime", "AiryBi", "AiryBiPrime", \
"AngerJ", "AngerJ2", "AppellF1", "ArithmeticGeometricMean", "Assert", \
"AugmentedSymmetricPolynomial", "AugmentedSymmetricPolynomialList", \
"BarnesG", "BellB", "BellB2", "BernoulliB", "BernoulliB2", \
"BernsteinBasis", "BesselI", "BesselJ", "BesselJZero", "BesselK", \
"BesselY", "BesselYZero", "Beta", "Beta3", "Beta4", \
"BetaRegularized", "BetaRegularized4", "BF", "Binomial", "Bra", \
"BraKet", "BSplineBasis", "BSplineBasis3", "BSplineBasis4", "Button", \
"CalculateInput", "CalculatePrompt", "CardinalBSplineBasis", \
"CarmichaelLambda", "CatalanNumber", "Ceiling", "CellExpression", \
"CellInsertionMenu", "CellInsertionMenuShortcut", "CellLabel", \
"CentralMoment", "CentralMomentList", "ChampernowneNumber", \
"Citation", "Code", "Column", "CompatibilityControls", \
"CompatibilityDocked1", "CompatibilityDocked2", "CompatibilityInput", \
"CompatibilityInputTop", "CompatibilityText", "CompatibilityTextTop", \
"ConditionedIntegrate", "ConditionedLimit", "ConditionedList", \
"ConditionedListWithAttributes", "ConditionedMax", "ConditionedMin", \
"ConditionedProduct", "ConditionedSet", \
"ConditionedSetWithAttributes", "ConditionedSum", "Conjugate", \
"ConjugateTranspose", "ControlStyle", "CoordinateTooltipLabel", \
"CopyEvaluate", "CopyEvaluateCell", "CoshIntegral", "CosIntegral", \
"Cumulant", "CumulantList", "Cyclotomic", "DawsonF", "DedekindEta", \
"DemosLink", "Deploy", "Det", "DialogStyle", "DialogText", \
"DifferenceDelta2", "DifferenceDelta3", "DifferenceDelta4", \
"DiracDeltaSeq", "DirichletCharacter", "DirichletL", \
"DiscreteDeltaSeq", "DiscreteRatio2", "DiscreteRatio3", \
"DiscreteRatio4", "DiscreteShift2", "DiscreteShift3", \
"DiscreteShift4", "DivisorSigma", "DockedCell", "DockedTitleCell", \
"DomainIntegrate", "DomainProduct", "DomainSum", "EllipticE", \
"EllipticE2", "EllipticF", "EllipticK", "EllipticNomeQ", \
"EllipticPi", "EllipticPi3", "EllipticTheta", "EllipticThetaPrime", \
"EulerE", "EulerE2", "EulerPhi", "Evaluate", "EvaluateCell", \
"EvaluationMarker", "ExpIntegralE", "ExpIntegralEi", \
"FactorialMoment", "FactorialMomentList", "FactorialPower", \
"FactorialPower3", "Fibonacci", "Fibonacci2", "FieldHintStyle", \
"Floor", "Footer", "FooterSection", "FooterSubsection", \
"FooterTitle", "FrameLabel", "FresnelC", "FresnelS", \
"FunctionTemplate", "FunctionTemplateArgument", \
"FunctionTemplateHighlight", "Gamma", "Gamma2", "Gamma3", \
"GammaRegularized", "GammaRegularized3", "GeneralizedPlaceholder", \
"GenericButton", "GenericLink", "GettingStartedLink", "Graphics", \
"Graphics3D", "Grid", "Gudermannian", "HankelH1", "HankelH2", \
"HarmonicNumber", "HarmonicNumber2", "Haversine", "Header", \
"HeaderSection", "HeaderSubsection", "HeaderTitle", \
"HeavisideLambdaSeq", "HeavisidePiSeq", "HeavisideThetaSeq", \
"HideContentsInPrint", "HistoryCurrentPage", "HurwitzLerchPhi", \
"HurwitzZeta", "Hypergeometric0F1", "Hypergeometric0F1Regularized", \
"Hypergeometric1F1", "Hypergeometric1F1Regularized", \
"Hypergeometric2F1", "Hypergeometric2F1Regularized", \
"HypergeometricU", "Hyperlink", "HyperlinkActive", "ImageGraphics", \
"Inert", "InfoCell", "InfoGrid", "InfoHeading", "InformationCell", \
"InformationLink", "InformationLinkLF", "InlineCell", \
"InlineCellEditing", "InlineOutput", "Input", "InputField", \
"InputForm", "InputOnly", "InsetString", "IntervalClosed", \
"IntervalClosedOpen", "IntervalOpen", "IntervalOpenClosed", \
"Inverse", "InverseBetaRegularized", "InverseBetaRegularized4", \
"InverseEllipticNomeQ", "InverseGammaRegularized", \
"InverseGammaRegularized3", "InverseGudermannian", \
"InverseHaversine", "InverseJacobiCD", "InverseJacobiCN", \
"InverseJacobiCS", "InverseJacobiDC", "InverseJacobiDN", \
"InverseJacobiDS", "InverseJacobiNC", "InverseJacobiND", \
"InverseJacobiNS", "InverseJacobiSC", "InverseJacobiSD", \
"InverseJacobiSN", "InverseWeierstrassP", "InverseWeierstrassP4", \
"IT", "ItemizedPicture", "JacobiAmplitude", "JacobiCD", "JacobiCN", \
"JacobiCS", "JacobiDC", "JacobiDN", "JacobiDS", "JacobiNC", \
"JacobiND", "JacobiNS", "JacobiSC", "JacobiSD", "JacobiSN", \
"JacobiSymbol", "JacobiZeta", "KelvinBei", "KelvinBei2", "KelvinBer", \
"KelvinBer2", "KelvinKei", "KelvinKei2", "KelvinKer", "KelvinKer2", \
"Ket", "KleinInvariantJ", "KroneckerDeltaSeq", "KroneckerSymbol", \
"Label", "Large", "LegendreP", "LegendreP3", "LegendreP4", \
"LegendreQ", "LegendreQ3", "LegendreQ4", "LerchPhi", "Link", \
"LiouvilleLambda", "ListGraphic", "LocatorPane", "LogGamma", \
"LogIntegral", "LucasL", "LucasL2", "MainBookLink", "MainBookLinkMR", \
"MangoldtLambda", "Manipulate", "ManipulateLabel", "Manipulator", \
"MasterIndexLink", "MathCaption", "MathieuCharacteristicA", \
"MathieuCharacteristicB", "MB", "MBO", "Medium", "Menu", "MenuLabel", 
 "MenuViewLabel", "Message", "MessageLink", "MessagesWindow", \
"MixedFraction", "MO", "Mod", "ModularLambda", "MoebiusMu", "Moment", \
"MomentList", "MR", "MSG", "NetworkEdge", "NetworkGraphics", \
"NetworkVertex", "NevilleThetaC", "NevilleThetaD", "NevilleThetaN", \
"NevilleThetaS", "NorlundB", "NorlundB3", "Norm", "Norm2", \
"NotationMadeBoxesTag", "NotationPatternTag", "NotationTemplateTag", \
"Notebook", "NotebookLink", "NotebookLinkMR", "Notes", "ObjectName", \
"OpenCloseItemizedPicture", "OtherInformationLink", \
"OtherInformationLinkMR", "Output", "OutputForm", "PageBreak", \
"PageLink", "PageNumber", "Pane", "Panel", "PanelLabel", \
"PaneSelector", "ParabolicCylinderD", "PartitionsP", "PartitionsQ", \
"Paste", "Picture", "PictureGroup", "Piecewise", "Placeholder", \
"PluginEmbeddedContent", "PluginEmbeddedWindow", "PluginInfoText", \
"PluginInitWindow", "PluginMainErrorText", "PluginSubErrorText", \
"PluginWindow", "Pochhammer", "PolyGamma", "PolyGamma2", "PolyLog", \
"PolyLog3", "PolynomialMod", "PopupMenu", "PopupMenuLabel", \
"PowerMod", "PowerSymmetricPolynomial", \
"PowerSymmetricPolynomialList", "PreviousNext", "PrimaryPlaceholder", \
"Prime", "PrimeNu", "PrimeOmega", "PrimePi", "PrimeZetaP", "Print", \
"PrintTemporary", "PrintUsage", "QBinomial", "QFactorial", "QGamma", \
"QHypergeometricPFQSeq", "QPochhammer", "QPochhammer1", \
"QPochhammer2", "QPolyGamma", "QPolyGamma3", "RamanujanTau", \
"Reference", "ReferenceMarker", "Residue", "RiemannR", \
"RiemannSiegelTheta", "RiemannSiegelZ", "RM", "RowDefault", \
"RowNoSeparators", "RowWithSeparator", "RowWithSeparators", "SB", \
"SBO", "SelectionPlaceholder", "SinhIntegral", "SinIntegral", \
"SlideHyperlink", "SlidePreviousNextLink", "SlideShowCanvas", \
"SlideShowNavigationBar", "SlideShowNavigationBar2", \
"SlideShowPaletteButton", "SlideShowPaletteTitle", \
"SlideShowSection", "SlideTOC", "SlideTOCLink", "Small", "SO", \
"Sound", "SphericalBesselJ", "SphericalBesselY", "SphericalHankelH1", \
"SphericalHankelH2", "SpheroidalEigenvalue", "SpheroidalPS", \
"SpheroidalPSPrime", "SpheroidalQS", "SpheroidalQSPrime", \
"SpheroidalS1", "SpheroidalS1Prime", "SpheroidalS2", \
"SpheroidalS2Prime", "SquaresR", "SR", "StandardForm", \
"StieltjesGamma", "StieltjesGamma2", "StirlingS1", "StirlingS2", \
"StruveH", "StruveL", "Subsuperscript", "Superscript", \
"TableViewGrid", "TableViewItem", "TableViewItem2", \
"TableViewItemExpression", "TableViewItemExpression2", \
"TableViewLabel", "TableViewPlaceholder", "TableViewStringBoxes", \
"TabView", "TabViewLabel", "TB", "TBI", \
"TemplateBoxErrorDisplayArgumentStyle", \
"TemplateBoxErrorDisplayStyle", "TemplateDockedCell", \
"TemplateHeaderCell", "TemplateLink", "TemplateVariable", "TextForm", \
"TextStyleInputField", "TextStyling", "TI", "TooltipLabel", \
"TourLink", "TR", "TraditionalForm", "Transpose", "UnitBoxSeq", \
"UnitStepSeq", "UnitTriangleSeq", "UnmatchedBracket", "Usage", \
"WeberE", "WeberE2", "WeierstrassP", "WeierstrassPPrime", \
"WeierstrassSigma", "WeierstrassZeta", "WhittakerM", "WhittakerW", \
"WolframAlphaLong", "WolframAlphaShort", "WolframAlphaShortInput", \
"Zeta", "Zeta2", "ZetaZero", All} *)
```

And to see which of these built-in named styles might be visually useful:

```
Grid[{Style["The quick brown fox ...", #], Style[#, #]} & /@ 
  Cases[styles, _String], Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Center}]
```

[image]

Comment: I had just thought of doing this when your answer showed up.  I was trying to find a built-in function.  (+1)

Comment: Note that `StyleData` can take a `StyleDefinitions` option, which your pattern doesn't account for.  So there are even more styles...

Comment: @BrettChampion good point. I'll make the changes

Comment: +1 but why not use `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets", "Core.nb"}]` in the first section?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard do not recall. I use `FileNameJoin` regularly now but maybe I wasn't aware of it then

Answer (score 27):

Version 10 introduced some undocumented functionality that makes it easier to explore the style hierarchy.  As usual, "undocumented" === "buyer beware".

We start by evaluating:

```
StyleManager`OpenStyleManager
```

This does nothing other than trigger the auto-loading of certain symbols.  We'll come back to a more interesting use of this symbol later.

Now, we can get a list of all styles accessible from a given notebook like this:

```
NotebookTools`StylesheetsDump`stylesInAllStylesheets[EvaluationNotebook[]] //
  Sort // Column

(*
  StyleData["Abs"]
  StyleData["ActionMenu"]
  StyleData["ActionMenuLabel"]
  StyleData["AddOnsLink"]
  <<749 more elements>>
  StyleData["Zeta2"]
  StyleData["ZetaZero"]
*)
```

We can find the style rule hierarchy that applies to any given style like this:

```
NotebookTools`StylesheetsDump`buildStyleData[StyleData["Input"]]
```

[image: style data dump]

A more readable presentation of this data can be obtained as well:

```
NotebookTools`StylesheetsDump`buildStyleData[StyleData["Input"]] //
  NotebookTools`StylesheetsDump`showStyleData
```

[image: formatted style data]

There is a dialog box that can be used to explore all of this data interactively (which appears to be a work in progress):

```
StyleManager`OpenStyleManager[]
```

[image: style manager screenshot]

This information is current as of *Mathematica* version 10.0.2, but could change at any time.

Comment: Great find!! :)

Comment: Is this still available in version 11.3? Or was it replaced with something similar/better?

Comment: @mmaSpectator Yes, this still works in 11.3 and also up to the current version (12.2).  I am not aware of an official replacement.