# Text and maths displaying weirdly

Tags: functions, text, display

So I'm trying to make a function to compute a bunch of descriptive statistics at once. What I've got so far:

```
DescriptiveStats[m_] := {Mean= Mean[m], Variance= Variance[m], 
  Median= Median[m], Max= Max[m], Min= Min[m], Skew= Skewness[m], 
  Kurtosis= Kurtosis[m]}
```

(can't seem to get a code block working sorry...)

In each of these, I'm using a text-cell for the bit that says (for example) Mean=

However, I end up getting the following display (using some randomly generated data):

```
{9.86873 TextCell["Mean="], 1.86686 TextCell["Variance="], 
 9.83039 TextCell["Median="], 14.3527 TextCell["Max="], 
 6.388 TextCell["Min="], 0.150053 TextCell["Skew="], 
 2.87745 TextCell["Kurtosis="]}
```

Any ideas as to why I'm getting this weird display and how I can fix it?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Thanks @Kuba! Definitely a duplicate, my bad, couldn't find it in my searching. And thanks for the warm welcome @Louis!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recommend that you use [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html) in definition of `DescriptiveStats`

```
DescriptiveStats[m_List] := 
 Row[{"Mean=", Mean[m], ", Variance=", Variance[m], "\nMedian=", 
   Median[m], ", Max=", Max[m], ", Min=", Min[m], "\nSkew=", 
   Skewness[m], ", Kurtosis=", Kurtosis[m]}]

data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 200];

DescriptiveStats[data]
```

[image]

Comment: That's done it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

[`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html) is the most versatile formatting function for producing tabular output. It allows almost endless twiddling with the look of the table. Here is a relatively simple example of what `Grid` cam do for your problem.

```
descriptiveStats[m_List] :=
  Grid[
    {{Mean, Mean[m], Median, Median[m]},
     {Min, Min[m], Max, Max[m]}, 
     {Skewness, Skewness[m], Kurtosis, Kurtosis[m]},
     {Variance, Variance[m], "", ""}},
    BaseStyle -> {"SR"},
    Dividers -> {3 -> {AbsoluteThickness[1.5], Black}},
    Alignment -> {{1 -> Left, 2 -> ".", 3 -> Left, 4 -> "."}}]

data = {1.21, 3.4, 2.15, 4, 15.5};
descriptiveStats[data]
```

[image: table]

Comment: What does "SR" stand for? (Is it "StandardReport"?) Do you have a link to the properties of this `BaseStyle`?

Comment: @Karsten7.  It stands for "Sans-serif Regular". Here is a [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29527/3066) for you to follow for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot! [Search](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22SR%22) couldn't find it. Also, nice Q&A I didn't see before.