# How to list all styles for current notebook?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, style

How can I programmatically list the available cell styles for the current notebook?

I am looking for the same list displayed in the Format → Style menu (which I know is not the exhaustive list of styles, but it does depend on the current stylesheet).

I need a way that can be used from a palette to get the style list of the currently selected notebook (and dynamically refresh it when selecting a different notebook).

[image]

Comment: ``FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`GetPopupList["MenuListStyles"]]//Column`` but I don't know how to use it for other than parent notebook. ([8606](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8606/5478))

Comment: @Kuba Thank you! Actually, as you guessed, I want to use it from a palette and dynamically refresh it as a new notebook is selected.

Comment: @Kuba Do you know how to make something like this update dynamically, preferably with no kernel interaction?

Comment: There was a question how to create such popup menu,   the context was to move menu from formatting toolbar to palette. I dont think fe side solution was provided. Will try to find it/investigate later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use the undocumented function `styleMenuStyles` to get the list of styles for a particular notebook:

```
StyleManager`OpenStyleManager;    (* to autoload symbols *)

EvaluationNotebook[] // NotebookTools`StylesheetsDump`styleMenuStyles // Map[First]

(*
   {"Title", "Chapter", "Subchapter", "Section", "Subsection",
    "Subsubsection", "Text", "Code", "Input", "Output", "Subtitle",
    "Subsubtitle", "Item", "ItemParagraph", "Subitem",
    "SubitemParagraph", "Subsubitem", "SubsubitemParagraph",
    "ItemNumbered", "SubitemNumbered", "SubsubitemNumbered",
    "InlineFormula", "DisplayFormula", "DisplayFormulaNumbered",
    "Program"}
*)
```

Similar undocumented style-related functions are discussed in [(71301)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71301/142).

Internally, `styleMenuStyles` uses a two-argument form of the function `` FEPrivate`GetPopUpList `` that [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) noted in a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156437/how-to-list-all-styles-for-current-notebook/156448#comment417463_156437).  Essentially:

```
FEPrivate`GetPopupList[EvaluationNotebook[], "MenuListStyles"] //
FE`Evaluate //
Cases[_[s_String, _] :> s]
```