# Unitalicizing a label with a sub/superscript

Tags: plotting, formatting

I need to use a sub/superscript to label the x-axis variable on the horizontal axis of my plot.

Mathematica returns the variable as italicized, but only the $x^2$ needs to be italicized, but not the subscript $g$.

I tried using both Subsuperscript and with the control+6 and _, but both yielded the same results.

Code:

```
ListPlot[{1, 4, 5}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> (
    {"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(g\)], \ \(2\)]\)", 
     "y"
    })]
```

Corresponding plot:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm adding this answer because I think it is the simplest solution.

```
ListPlot[{1, 4, 5},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {Subsuperscript[x, g, 2], y}]
```

[image: plot]

#### Edit

Johu has a raised a valid issue in his comment. Here is a solution that addresses it.

```
ListPlot[{1, 4, 5},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {Subsuperscript[Style["x", "TI"], Style["g", "TR"], "2"], "y"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If someone asks where the mystical `"TI"` and `"TR"` styles come from: They are heavily used in the reference pages. So if you see something like this in the documentation

> [image: img]

you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to see the underlying box-expression and you will note that the same style-definitions are used.

#### Note

Quite a lot of information on named styles such `"TR"` can be found on [this page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29527/3066)

Comment: -1 as g is still italic?

Comment: @Johu. Valid point. I have addressed it in an edit to the answer

Comment: Thank you all!! :) Greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Now it is a really over-complicated solution. `"TR"` does the same as `FontSlant -> "Plain"` which does nothing to solve this problem. Making subscript to `String` is what makes the difference and it also makes sense semantically.

Comment: For example `TraditionalForm[Style[Subscript[x, g], FontSlant -> Plain]]` gives still italic text.

Comment: @Johu One advantage of having the style defined like this is that it doesn't get destroyed when you set e.g. `FrameStyle -> Italic`. In this case every tick and label would be italic, but your styled $x^2_g$ keeps its format.

Comment: @halirutan I agree to that.

Answer (score 3):

```
ListPlot[{1, 4, 5}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Tiny, 
  FrameLabel -> ({Subsuperscript[x, "g", 2], "y"})]~Magnify~3
```

[image]

I think it happens because `StandardForm` for output plots has `TraditionalForm` applied to it. `TraditionalForm` formats differently `String`-s and `Symbol`-s. Example:

```
Magnify[Subsuperscript["x", "g", 2] // TraditionalForm, 2]
Magnify[Subsuperscript[x, "g", 2] // TraditionalForm, 2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, it is better to avoid linear syntax strings (the kind of strings you get when you apply 2D typesetting structures inside of a string) and instead just use expressions. So, I like this:

```
Superscript[Subscript[x, g], 2]
```

instead of:

```
"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(g\)], \ \(2\)]\)"
```

Now, the reason that some characters get italicized is because by default [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot) renders labels in [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm), and [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) uses the option [`SingleLetterItalics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SingleLetterItalics)->[`True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/True). So, to avoid having `g` italicized, you could override this with:

```
FrameLabel -> {Superscript[Subscript[x, Style[g, Plain]], 2], y}
```

or:

```
FrameLabel -> {Superscript[Subscript[x, "g"], 2], y}
```

where the latter works because "g" is not a single letter *symbol*.

Visualization:

```
ListPlot[
    {1, 4, 5},
    Frame -> True,
    FrameLabel -> {Superscript[Subscript[x, Style[g, Plain]], 2], y}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's also a typical usage case for the [MaTeX-package](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX) by Szabolcs:

```
Needs["MaTeX`"]
ListPlot[{1, 4, 5}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> ({MaTeX["x_{\\mathrm{g}}^2"], MaTeX["y"]})
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Latex `\operatorname` has a different semantical meaning. `\mathrm` or [`\text` from `amsmath`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3415/what-is-the-correct-way-of-embedding-text-into-math-mode) would be more precise.

Comment: Good point although I would avoid `\text` for subscripts because `\textit{$x_{\text{g}}$}` would be again in italics -- and theorems are usually typeset in italics.